# RegEx: First <br> within a paragraph

Tags: php, html, regex, laravel

How to capture and remove the first occurrence of a `<br/>` tag within a paragraph.

```
<p><br/>Hello World</p>
```

Becomes:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

But importantly the following remains unchanged:

```
<p><br/></p>
```

> Remove leading `<br>` tags from paragraphs that contain text

---

What I have so far:

```
preg_replace('/(<p>\s*<br *\/?>(.*?)<\/p>)+/si', '<p>$2</p>', $html);
```

Although this captures `<p><br></p>` instances...

Comment: You want to remove first occurrence of <br/>, right? For that, you only have a couple of possibilities such as <p><br/>Hello World</p>, <p><br/></p> and <p>     <br/>Hello World</p>. Am I correct?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Is there a parent element above the `<p>`?

Comment: `<p><br/> </p>` is also a case that should not be matched.

Comment: Should the `<br>` be deleted from `<p><br/> </p>`? i.e. `<p>` elements that contain only spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would do it using PHP's built in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) classes:

```
$html = "<div><p><br/>Hello World</p><p><br/></p><p> <br> </p></div>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// find <br> within a <p> that has text content
$breaks = $xpath->query("//p[normalize-space()!='']/br");
$breaks = $xpath->query("//p[text()!='']/br");
// and remove them
foreach ($breaks as $br) {
    $br->parentNode->removeChild($br);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Note that there are two lines assigning values to `$breaks`. You should use the one which meets your requirements: the first will only strip `<br>` from elements which have non-whitespace characters between the `<p>` and `</p>`, while the second will also strip them from `<p>` elements containing only whitespace. The different effects can be seen in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/qFbdS).

Answer (score 0):

If there are more rules, we can pass array in `preg_replace`. In my solution, first element in pattern will look for `<br />` with text. and second will look for just `<br />` without text. Also this search is made from the beginng of the string (`/^..`).

```
preg_replace(['/^(<p>\s*(<br *\/?>)([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)<\/p>)+/si', '/^(<p>\s*(<br *\/?>)<\/p>)+/si'], ['<p>$3</p>', '$0'], $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a recommended way to parse html with regex. But just for a quick and temporary work, you may use this regex to capture a linebreak `<br/>` that is preceded by `<p>` tag and some text and do a lookahead that it should not be immediately followed by closing `</p>` tag.

```
<p>.*?\K<br\/>(?!<\/p>)
```

and replace such captured `<br/>` with empty string hence removing it.

**Explanation:**

- `<p>.*?` --> Match a paragraph tag followed by any characters in non-greedy way
- `\K` --> Reset whatever matched as we don't intend to replace that
- `<br\/>(?!<\/p>)` --> Match a line break tag that is not immediately followed by closing paragraph tag, which will be replaced with empty string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cKYeSo/1)

Here are sample php codes,

```
$html = '<p><br/>Hello World</p>';
$html = preg_replace('/<p>.*?\K<br\/>(?!<\/p>)/si', '', $html);
echo $html. "\n";


$html = '<p><br/></p>';
$html = preg_replace('/<p>.*?\K<br\/>(?!<\/p>)/si', '', $html);
echo $html. "\n";
```

Which prints following output,

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<p><br/></p>
```